# ruby sftp error password reset

Tags: ruby, linux, sftp

I am troubleshooting a ruby script that queries a database, creates a csv, and sftps it to another server.  The server the script is on is a rhel box, running ruby 1.87 I believe.

Here's the code that does the sftping:

```
Net::SFTP.start(sftp_site, sftp_user, :password => sftp_pswd) do |sftp|       
    sftp.upload!(local_filepath,sftp_dir+filename)  
end
```

When executing the script, there is a curious message before it bombs out:

```
Password Reset

Your password has expired. You are required to change your password to proceed.
```

This script works on another server, but not this one.  A user can sftp from the prompt on this machine.  SELinux has been turned off, as it may have had some interference.

Anyway, point being, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: is the same, exact username and password used when testing the script on the machine that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: Are you using MySQL? Make sure this remote host has been granted permissions to connect.

Comment: @Alpha01, no, it's not using MySQL.  It's using Oracle, and I know that part is working because it is creating the files.  
I asked someone who can access this machine to get all of the gems installed.  Possibly this is gem issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared to be a gem issue (though someone in networking may have worked some magic I am unaware of).  The production server had older versions of the net/ssh and net/sftp gems.  It had version 1.1.1 and version 1.1.2, respectively, and upgrading those gems to a later version fixed the issue.

Thanks for everyone who offered suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the sshd daemon settings (sshd_config), as there's likely an issue in the server that's not working.  Perhaps interactive-keyboard authentication is turned on or something like that?

Comment: I will look at that as soon as I am able to.  Thanks so much for giving me alternative areas to look!

Comment: All indications appear to be SSH related.  [http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/wiki/Red_Hat_Bug_124602_In_Action](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/wiki/Red_Hat_Bug_124602_In_Action)